# Appcelerator - Titanium | List of openable files

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm currently working on an application that one of the availabe function will be that a file is downloaded on the device and then opened, only when their is an application that can open it.

I have been browsing the API / Q&A / Google and couldn't find anything useful.

Anyone have a suggestion how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using property while you open file add that name in your List and set it into array while you close that window remove from List and set your array into property.

```
var objFileArray = Ti.App.Properties.getList('fileArray',[]);
objFileArray.push('File1');
Ti.App.Properties.setList('fileArray', objFileArray);
```